# Why is my regex in Swift not compiling? How do I give it a mutable string instead?

Tags: ios, regex, swift, nsregularexpression

When I use the following code to strip the `http://` and `www.` off the beginning of a URL, I get an error.

```
var error: NSError? = nil
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^(http(s)?://)?(www(\\d)?\\.)?", options: nil, error: &error)

var stringy = "http://www.google.com/"
regex.replaceMatchesInString(stringy, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(stringy)), withTemplate: "")
```

The error being:

> 'NSString' is not a subtype of 'NSMutableString'

How do I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How [*does* `replaceMatcehsInString` work](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRegularExpression/replaceMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate:)? Why does it *not* accept a non-mutable string? It has naught to do with "regex [..] not compiling". Compare with `stringByReplacingMatchesInString`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `stringy` an `NSMutableString` by simply constructing it with `NSMutableString(string: ...)`. You'll also have to do a few other things to get your code to work though:

1. You can't pass `nil` for options. If you don't want to pass any options, the correct value is `NSMatchingOptions.allZeros`
2. In Xcode 6.1 GM, the `init` method you're using for `NSRegularExpression` returns an Optional (`NSRegularExpression?`), so you'll need to use optional chaining to call `regex?.replaceMatchesInString`. (This may not be the case in Xcode 6.0.1; I'm not sure when that change was made)
3. Since `stringy` is an `NSMutableString` now, you can't call `countElements()` on it. Just use `NSString`'s length property instead.

With those changes in place, the code looks like:

```
var error: NSError? = nil
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^(http(s)?://)?(www(\\d)?\\.)?",
    options: nil, error: &error)

var stringy = NSMutableString(string: "http://www.google.com")
regex?.replaceMatchesInString(stringy, options: NSMatchingOptions.allZeros,
    range: NSMakeRange(0, stringy.length), withTemplate: "")
```

Then calling `println(stringy)` after it's executed outputs:

> google.com

Comment: As of Swift 2.2 #1 needs to be `[]` rather than `NSMatchingOptions.allZeros ` or `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me knowing if this gets you where you want:

```
let oldString = "http://www.google.com/"

let newString = oldString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("^(http(s)?://)?(www(\\d)?\\.)?", withString:"" as NSString, options:NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range:nil)
println(newString) //  google.com/
```

Comment: +1, works over here, way better than doing it with `NSRegularExpression`.